# routerLinkActive does not update Hyperlink, when route.params id is changed

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

That is my plunkr:

https://plnkr.co/edit/C9W0pHvy27J83m25YUOJ?p=preview

These are the steps to retrace the problem:

1. Open project 'neverending'
2. the url shows `/projects/1/tests` then
3. The 'Tests link' is orange highlighted
4. change the route in the url bar to `/projects/2/tests`
5. the formerly highlighted 'Tests link' is now NOT orange anymore.

Why is the active class removed by angular?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently this does not work, see [#13865](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/13865)

Comment: if we continue with that game you owe me in the end your full 5000K scores :P

Answer (score 2):

I faced this issue. Actually my route needs to change from `projects/1/test` to `projects/2/test`, where 1 and 2 are params in the url that may change. so I resolved it by following technique:

```
<a routerLink="/projects/:id/test" routerLinkActive="on" 
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false, __change_detection_hack__: id }">
   Link 
</a>
```

where `__change_detection_hack__` detects changes in the url and `id` is your url param name.

**Note:** if you are setting `routerLink` with some variable then you should do something like this:

```
<a [routerLink]="myStringVar" routerLinkActive="on" 
   [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: false, __change_detection_hack__: someVariable }">
   Link
</a>
```

for detailed discussion, please visit [here](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/18469#issuecomment-345436335)

Answer (score 0):

```
***app.module.ts***    


  { path: 'projects', component: ProjectListComponent , children: [
    { path: '', redirectTo: 'tests', pathMatch: 'full' }, /* projects/id causes can not match any route */
    { path: ':id/tests', component: TestsListComponent },
    ]
  },

  { path: '', redirectTo: 'projects', pathMatch: 'full' },
   { path: '**', component: NoRouteFoundComponent } /

];
```

**projects-list.component.html**

```
 <nav style="background:gray;">
      <select (ngModelChange)="onChangeProject($event)" [(ngModel)]="currentProject">
                <option *ngFor="let p of projects" [ngValue]="p">
                    {{p.name}}
                </option>
            </select> 
            <button [disabled]="!currentProject"  (click)="open()">Open project</button>


            <a *ngIf="isMenuVisible" [routerLink]="['/projects', currentProject.id, 'tests']"
    [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true, __change_detection_hack__: currentProject.id }" >Tests link
            </a>


        <span>Logged out</span>
```

You should add :
 [routerLinkActiveOptions]="{ exact: true, **change_detection_hack**: currentProject.id }"

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO. Please explain your answer (with example if possible). This can help others with similar problem use your answer.

Comment: hope that helps